# Running nltk module with python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I have installed python 38 on my PC (Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit).  It is in the following directory;

C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

I then downloaded nltk-3.5 (the download is a zip file obtained irectly from the nltk website) and I unzipped it and placed the files in the python Lib directory.

C:\Users\rschafish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\nltk-3.5

I opened python using IDLE (Python 3.8.3 Shell) and the opening line from python includes;

(Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020 22:20:19 MSC vl1925 32 bit Intel on win32)

I then entered >>> import nltk  and received the following error message;

Traceback (most recent call last): File”<pyshell#0>”, line 1 in  import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named ’nltk’

It appears that this may be a problem related to the python path however I thought that placing the nltk files in the python Lib directory is what should be done.  I have searched the issue online but did not find any solutions that have worked for me.

Help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't just unzip libraries into that folder and get it recognized by "import", you need to "install" packages properly. Follow the installation instructions here: https://www.nltk.org/install.html

Comment: You can use pip: `py -3.8-32 -m pip install -U nltk` to properly install NLTK. The download and install takes a while, so be patient. I ran this successfully recently for python 3.9 64-bit. Use py -3.8-32 to install to exactly the same python as IDLE. Before the download, I `set NLTK_DATA=c:\Users\me\nltk_data` first so I would not need admin privs.